# Accessing the camera and photo library in swift 4

Tags: ios, swift, camera, photolibrary, phphotolibrary

I'm trying to access both the camera and photo library in swift4 using the following code

```
let imagePickerController = UIImagePickerController()
    imagePickerController.delegate = self
    let alert = UIAlertController(title: "", message: "", preferredStyle: .actionSheet)
    alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Camera", style: .default, handler: {(action: UIAlertAction) in
        imagePickerController.sourceType = .camera
        print(1)
    }))
    alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Photo Album", style: .default, handler: {(action: UIAlertAction) in
        imagePickerController.sourceType = .photoLibrary
    }))
    alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Cancel", style: .default, handler: nil))
    self.present(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

but it's not working. I'm not get an access authorization request even though I made sure that the plist has the camera and photo library authorization. I manipulate the code a bit to the following

```
AVCaptureDevice.requestAccess(for: AVMediaType.video) { response in
    }
    let photos = PHPhotoLibrary.authorizationStatus()
    if photos == .notDetermined {
        PHPhotoLibrary.requestAuthorization({status in
        })
    }

    let imagePickerController = UIImagePickerController()
    imagePickerController.delegate = self
    let alert = UIAlertController(title: "", message: "", preferredStyle: .actionSheet)
    alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Camera", style: .default, handler: {(action: UIAlertAction) in
        imagePickerController.sourceType = .camera
        print(1)
    }))
    alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Photo Album", style: .default, handler: {(action: UIAlertAction) in
        imagePickerController.sourceType = .photoLibrary
    }))
    alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Cancel", style: .default, handler: nil))
    self.present(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

Now I am getting the authorization request for both cameras and photo library and I can see the AlertView but when I press camera or Photo Album as shown in the picture nothing happens.

[image]

I tried on a device and simulator for the camera.

Comment: You can present the uiImagepickercontroller in alert action with particular source type camera and photolibrary or take permission code in this alert action

Comment: Can you elaborate more

Comment: Did you added **UINavigationControllerDelegate**  ??

Comment: yup I added UINavigationControllerDelegate &&UIImagePickerControllerDelegate

Comment: you have to add **present(imagePickerController, animated: true, completion: nil)** after your source type.

Comment: i did check the last line of the code

Comment: yes but that was for alert presentation.If you want to select images from camera of library you must have to present you imageController picker.

Comment: it work only with the photo doesnot work with camera

Comment: check in device.Simulator not supported camera.

Comment: That not correct you present the alert because there are two options. if you choose imagepicker controller you are just assiging it to photolibrary. You dont get the alertViewController if you do  present(imagePickerController, animated: true, completion: nil)

Comment: you have to redirect after selection of camera or photoLibrary .so that time you must present your imagePicker .If you are not assign that then you can not redirect to Photos or Camera . So you have to present your ImagePickerController. Refer Link :: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiimagepickercontroller

Comment: thanks I will check it. It is working now

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Here is the code to load image from photos & camera in iOS.

⁃   You need to create an outlet of your UIImageView

⁃   Then add a tap gesture on to image view

⁃   Then connect tap gesture with the didTapOnImageView function.

⁃   Then add the following extension to your view controller.

```
//MARK:- Image Picker
extension YourViewController: UIImagePickerControllerDelegate, UINavigationControllerDelegate {

    //This is the tap gesture added on my UIImageView.
    @IBAction func didTapOnImageView(sender: UITapGestureRecognizer) {
        //call Alert function
        self.showAlert()
    }

    //Show alert to selected the media source type.
    private func showAlert() {

        let alert = UIAlertController(title: "Image Selection", message: "From where you want to pick this image?", preferredStyle: .actionSheet)
        alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Camera", style: .default, handler: {(action: UIAlertAction) in
            self.getImage(fromSourceType: .camera)
        }))
        alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Photo Album", style: .default, handler: {(action: UIAlertAction) in
            self.getImage(fromSourceType: .photoLibrary)
        }))
        alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Cancel", style: .destructive, handler: nil))
        self.present(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }

    //get image from source type
    private func getImage(fromSourceType sourceType: UIImagePickerController.SourceType) {

        //Check is source type available
        if UIImagePickerController.isSourceTypeAvailable(sourceType) {

            let imagePickerController = UIImagePickerController()
            imagePickerController.delegate = self
            imagePickerController.sourceType = sourceType
            self.present(imagePickerController, animated: true, completion: nil)
        }
    }

    //MARK:- UIImagePickerViewDelegate.
    func imagePickerController(_ picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [UIImagePickerController.InfoKey : Any]) {

        self.dismiss(animated: true) { [weak self] in

            guard let image = info[UIImagePickerController.InfoKey.originalImage] as? UIImage else { return }
            //Setting image to your image view
            self?.profileImgView.image = image
        }
    }

    func imagePickerControllerDidCancel(_ picker: UIImagePickerController) {
        picker.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
    }

}
```

Note: Don't forget to add the privacy settings in info.plist

Privacy - Camera Usage Description

Privacy - Photo Library Usage Description

Comment: Very useful for me. Thanks!

Answer (score 10):

First of all, you need to import these libraries:

```
import Photos
import UIKit

 @IBOutlet weak var loadPhoto: UIButton!
```

And you need setup delegates:

```
class YourClass: UIViewController, UIImagePickerControllerDelegate, UINavigationControllerDelegate, UNUserNotificationCenterDelegate 

func displayUploadImageDialog(btnSelected: UIButton) {
    let picker = UIImagePickerController()
    picker.delegate = self
    picker.allowsEditing = true
    let alertController = UIAlertController(title: "", message: "Upload profile photo?".localized(), preferredStyle: .actionSheet)
    let cancelAction = UIAlertAction(title: NSLocalizedString("Cancel", comment: "Cancel action"), style: .cancel, handler: {(_ action: UIAlertAction) -> Void in
        alertController.dismiss(animated: true) {() -> Void in }
    })
    alertController.addAction(cancelAction)
    let cameraRollAction = UIAlertAction(title: NSLocalizedString("Open library".localized(), comment: "Open library action"), style: .default, handler: {(_ action: UIAlertAction) -> Void in
        if UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM() == .pad {
            OperationQueue.main.addOperation({() -> Void in
                picker.sourceType = .photoLibrary
                self.present(picker, animated: true) {() -> Void in }
            })
        }
        else {
            picker.sourceType = .photoLibrary
            self.present(picker, animated: true) {() -> Void in }
        }
    })
    alertController.addAction(cameraRollAction)
    alertController.view.tintColor = .black
    present(alertController, animated: true) {() -> Void in }
}

func imagePickerController(_ picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [String : Any]) {
    let image = info[UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage] as! UIImage
    profileImage.image = image
    let imageData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(image, 0.05)
    self.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
}

func checkPermission() {
    let authStatus = AVCaptureDevice.authorizationStatus(for: AVMediaType.video)
    switch authStatus {
    case .authorized:
        self.displayUploadImageDialog(btnSelected: self.loadPhoto)
    case .denied:
        print("Error")
    default:
        break
    }
}

func imagePickerControllerDidCancel(picker: UIImagePickerController) {
    self.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
}

func checkLibrary() {
    let photos = PHPhotoLibrary.authorizationStatus()
    if photos == .authorized {
        switch photos {
        case .authorized:
            self.displayUploadImageDialog(btnSelected: self.loadPhoto)
        case .denied:
            print("Error")
        default:
            break
        }
    }
}
```

Setup action for button:

```
@IBAction func loadPhotoTapped(_ sender: UIButton) {
    let photos = PHPhotoLibrary.authorizationStatus()
    if photos == .notDetermined {
        PHPhotoLibrary.requestAuthorization({status in
            if status == .authorized{
                print("OKAY")
            } else {
                print("NOTOKAY")
            }
        })
    }
    checkLibrary()
    checkPermission()
}
```

At the Info.plist setup the permissions:

> Privacy - Media Library Usage Description
>
> Privacy - Photo Library Usage Description
>
> Privacy - Camera Usage Description

This should work.

Comment: What's the point of your UserNotifications import? Did I overlook something?