# Why is photo library not displaying when I select it in swift?

Tags: ios, swift, photo-gallery

Using [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52399079/accessing-the-camera-and-photo-library-in-swift-4) question I ask the user to decide whether they want to use the camera or choose an image from their phone:

```
//Show alert to select the media source type.
    private func showAlert() {

        let alert = UIAlertController(title: "Image Selection", message: "From where you want to pick this image?", preferredStyle: .actionSheet)
        alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Camera", style: .default, handler: {(action: UIAlertAction) in
            self.imagePicker.sourceType = .camera
        }))
        alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Photo Album", style: .default, handler: {(action: UIAlertAction) in
            self.imagePicker.sourceType = .photoLibrary
        }))
        alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Cancel", style: .destructive, handler: nil))
            self.present(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
```

Which I envoke in `viewDidLoad` as such:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        firstTextField.delegate = self
        showAlert()
        present(imagePicker, animated: true, completion: nil)
        imagePicker.delegate = self
        firstImageView.layer.cornerRadius = 8
        
    }
```

However when I test this the alert pops up and I choose the photo library, but the library does not appear. I have tried using `viewDidAppear` but that failed to work as well. No errors appear, it just hides the alert and shows the current view controller.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may be imagining that code comes to a stop when an alert appears. But it doesn't! And you cannot show two presented view controllers simultaneously. But that is what you are trying to do.

You are saying `showAlert()`, so now your alert is up, and then you are immediately saying `present(imagePicker)`, which you cannot do because your alert is still up.

Use the action handlers of the `showAlert` alert to present the image picker. That way, the alert closes and the image picker opens.